# Twilio: cannot rename subdomain null for SIP termination

Tags: web-services, twilio, asterisk, sip, voip

In relation to [SIP registration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/pv-sip-registration), simply trying to add termination URI:

> Termination URI
>
> Configure a SIP Domain Name to uniquely identify your Termination SIP
>   URI for this Trunk. This URI will be used by your communications
>   infrastructure to direct SIP traffic towards Twilio. When you point
>   your infrastructure toward this URI, Twilio uses a Geo DNS lookup to
>   intelligently direct your traffic to our closest POP. Learn more about
>   Termination Settings

I can add `<foo>.pstn.twilio.com` fine, but get an error or suggestion:

> Please add at least one IP Access Control List or Credential List
>   before saving your Termination settings.

Fair enough.  Adding an IP Access Control List by clicking in the box generates:

> Cannot rename subdomain null because the parent domain does not exist
>   or this account doesn't own it.

I don't even know what to make of that.  The IP Access Control List is already in the Twilio dashboard, I just selected a value already stored.

It's the same error message regardless of whether `IP Access Control Lists` or `Credential Lists` is used.  In both cases, the values are configured and in the web dashboard.

see also:

[Twilio origination and termination SIP URI's with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590611/)